# error en funcion max() mysql

Tags: mysql

estoy intentado traer el nombre de un paciente con un inner join a otra tabla pero me marca error la funcion max()

intento traer el ultimo paciente que fue atentido por el mismo doctor y hacer un inner join a la tabla doctores para traerme el nombre del doctor

aqui ya tengo el error

```
select id_paciente,max(creado) as fecha from pacientes  where referencia=1
```

haci quisiera que quedara

```
select d.nombre,max(creado) as fechaultima from doctores d inner join pacientes p on d.id_doctor=p.id_doctor where referencia = 1
```

Comment: falta el `from`  y es recomendable colacar la refencia a la tabla ejemplo `max(p.creado)`

Comment: select p.nombre_completo,max(p.creado) as fecha from pacientes p where p.referencia=1 ya lo intente igual pero me marca error

Comment: haci me lo marca bien select max(p.creado) as fecha from pacientes p where p.referencia=1 pero necesito el nombre tambien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estas haciendo referencia a la tabla `pacientes` que contiene el campo `creado`, debe ser:

```
p.creado
```

realiza de esta forma tu consulta:

```
select d.nombre,max(p.creado) as fechaultima from doctores d inner join pacientes p on d.id_doctor=p.id_doctor where referencia = 1
```

---

Si obtienes el error:

> 1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT
>   list contains nonaggregated column 'ncrm_piedica.p.nombre_completo';
>   this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by –

usa  `group by` ya que en este caso es necesario una función de agregación :

```
select d.nombre_completo,max(p.creado) as fechaultima from doctores d inner join pacientes p on d.id_doctor=p.id_doctor where referencia = 1 group by d.nombre_completo
```

Comment: si quedo si pongo select d.nombre,max(p.creado) as fechaultima from doctores d inner join pacientes p on d.id_doc=p.referencia where referencia = 1

Comment: pero si lo pongo haci marca error select p.nombre_completo,max(p.creado) as fechaultima from doctores d inner join pacientes p on d.id_doc=p.referencia where referencia = 1

Comment: necesito el nombre del paciente no el de doctor

Comment: Que error obtienes @CarlosEnriqueGilGil

Comment: 1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'ncrm_piedica.p.nombre_completo'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Si usas una función de agregación como max, te hace falta agrupar por la otra columna que llamas en l select @Elenasys ?

Comment: solo necesito el nombre del paciente pero se me hace raro este error ya habia ocupado muchas veces el max() y no me marcaba este error no se si sea por la verision de mysql

Comment: Prueba agrupando los resultados, pues te hace falta ya que ocupas una función de agregación

Comment: @Aprendiz De acuerdo a lo que comentas, precisamente acabo de ver : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil realiza el query agregando "group by" de esta forma: select d.nombre_completo,max(p.creado) as fechaultima from doctores d inner join pacientes p on d.id_doctor=p.id_doctor where referencia = 1 group by d.nombre_completo

Comment: Si, pues si el OP dice que antes lo pudo hacer es por que el ONLY FULL GROUP lo tenía deshabilitado

Comment: @Elenasys si funciona pero me trae todos los pacientes ya no funciona el max(p.creado) a lo mejor estoy enredando mucho pero en si necesito solo el nombre del ultimo paciente atentindo por ese doctor y si se puede el total de pacientes que ha atentido

Comment: algo como esto select p.nombre_completo ,count(id_paciente) from pacientes p inner join doctores d on d.id_doc = p.referencia where p.referencia = $id

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil será de mucha ayuda si en tu pregunta colocas una muestra de los datos de entrada y una muestra de los datos de salida que esperas recibir de modo que podamos reproducir en la medida de lo posible tu escenario y darte una respuesta mas acertada